# Microsoft Virtual PC installation

Tags: installation, microsoft-virtual-pc

I am trying to run an old Windows 16-bit application. I'm running Windows 7 SP1 64-bit.

I downloaded Virtual PC via steps 2 and 3 of the following link:

> http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/download.aspx

During installation of Windows Virtual PC I get the following error in the event log:

> {Cannot install widnows update because
>   of error} 2149842967 "" (Command Line:
>   ""C:\Windows\system32\wusa.exe"
>   "C:\Users\Sergey\Downloads\Windows6.1-KB958559-x64-RefreshPkg
>   (1).msu"

*(Text in { } is approximate translation from Russian to English.)*

When I try to run Windows XP Mode, it says:

> Cannot launch main process Windows
>   Virtual PC

When I click Windows Virtual PC it shows an empty folder.

Any ideas?

Comment: Perform a Clean Boot and try the install again....http://logitech-en-amr.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/228/~/booting-clean-in-windows-7,-vista,-xp,-me-and-98#vista_7

Comment: Try using `DOSBox` to run that old app, instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternative solution which works for me fine - http://www.virtualbox.org/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that Virtualization is enabled in your BIOS. It might also be a good idea to update your BIOS.

I assume that since you are running Windows 7, your PC probably has a new enough processor, but you should download "Software Information for Windows", determine what your processor is, and then check the specs on the Intel site (or AMD) to make sure it even supports virtualization. You can also run this tool:

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=592

http://www.gtopala.com/

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itproappcompat/thread/61e16760-a500-481e-a90c-9b933f0fced8

That error code is related to directly to virtualization.